# Heroku deployment of rails engine within rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I'm having troubles with trying to deploy a rails engine with its own table inside of another rails app with a separate table.  Using Rails 3.2.16, ruby 2.0 under windows 7 I can access the postgres tables on Heroku without a problem all works fine.  When I deploy the app to heroku it seems to compile fine and until I try to envoke the app then I get errors.  I have read what I could find on the topic made sure all my gems have version numbers specified but I'm missing something any help would be appreciated.  I have successfully deployed a test app but seems to be having issues with the rails engine. This is my Heroku logs:

```
2014-03-21T14:59:07.088717+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-21T14:59:07.088717+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-03-21T14:59:07.088938+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2014-03-21T14:59:07.088938+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2014-03-21T14:59:07.088938+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-21T14:59:07.088938+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
2014-03-21T14:59:07.088717+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-03-21T14:59:07.088717+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2014-03-21T14:59:07.088938+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-03-21T14:59:07.088938+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2014-03-21T14:59:07.088938+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2014-03-21T14:59:07.088938+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2014-03-21T14:59:07.088938+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2014-03-21T14:59:07.088938+00:00 
app[web.1]:     from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2014-03-21T14:59:08.400418+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-03-21T14:59:08.389132+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-03-21T14:59:17.693130+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=stark-retreat-6591.herokuapp.com request_id=c9ad50bf-1436-47ae-92f0-f98047ae4547 fwd="128.104.84.224" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-21T15:07:52+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-03-21T15:09:05+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-03-21T15:09:05.592416+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 3a7c2f8 by dons@surgery.wisc.edu
2014-03-21T15:09:05.592521+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v30 created by dons@surgery.wisc.edu
2014-03-21T15:09:06.001749+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-03-21T15:09:09.226536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 11706`
2014-03-21T15:09:13.113288+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-03-21T15:09:13.113288+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.16 application starting in production on http://"was_all_zeros":11706
2014-03-21T15:09:13.113288+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2014-03-21T15:09:13.113288+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2014-03-21T15:09:13.113288+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-03-21T15:09:13.161278+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162124+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162124+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162124+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:27:in `spec'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162124+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162124+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/engine/authorize/app/models/authorize/user.rb:35:in `<class:User>'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162124+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162124+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162309+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162124+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/engine/authorize/app/models/authorize/user.rb:32:in `<module:Authorize>'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162124+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/engine/authorize/app/models/authorize/user.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162124+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162309+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162309+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162309+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162309+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162309+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162309+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/engine/authorize/app/controllers/authorize/users_controller.rb:4:in `<module:Authorize>'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163025+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163025+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162309+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162309+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `safe_constantize'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162309+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:260:in `safe_constantize'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:152:in `_default_wrap_model'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/engine/authorize/app/controllers/authorize/users_controller.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163025+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163025+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163204+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `eager_load!'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163204+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163204+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163204+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163204+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163204+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163025+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:169:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.162490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:133:in `inherited'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163025+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/engine.rb:441:in `each'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163025+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/engine.rb:441:in `eager_load!'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163204+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163025+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/engine.rb:444:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163025+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/engine.rb:443:in `each'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163025+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/engine.rb:443:in `block in eager_load!'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163204+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163204+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163655+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163655+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163655+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163204+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163655+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163655+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163655+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `require'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163655+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163655+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163655+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163655+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-03-21T15:09:13.163852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2014-
```

Comment: Similar problem here